# after networkx library update nx.connected_component_subgraphs(G), this error genarated

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph, networkx

```
gen=(G1.subgraph(c) for c in nx.connected_components(G1))

G1_LCC=max((G1.subgraph(c) for c in nx.connected_components(G1)),key=len)

G2_LCC=max((G2.subgraph(c) for c in nx.connected_components(G2)),key=len)

plt.figure()
nx.draw(G1_LCC,node_color="red",edge_color="grey",node_size="20")
plt.savefig("vill1.pdf")
```

> what's wrong with it? this is showing error.

```
TypeError: ufunc 'sqrt' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''
```

Answer (score 2):

You get a `TypeError` because `node_size` is supposed to be either a scalar or an array but you are passing a string ([docs](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw_networkx.html#networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw_networkx)).

Changing the value of node size to a scalar will solve the issue.

```
nx.draw(G1_LCC, node_color="red", edge_color="grey", node_size=20)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, a 'size' value is not a string. Try with int or float.

```
nx.draw(G1_LCC, node_color="red", edge_color="grey", node_size=20)
```